# After installing Visual Studio 2019 I can't find gacutil.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2019, gacutil

I'm trying to install gacutil in order to remove some assemblies from the GAC.  My understanding is that it's included with Visual Studio, so I installed Visual Studio Community Edition 2019.  gacutil.exe does not seem to be included with the installation.  What am I missing?

Comment: It is an SDK tool.  The install location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\gacutil.exe

Comment: I only have 'Portable', 'Windows Kits', and 'Windows Phone' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs'.

Comment: I am getting the error "failure adding assembly to the cache: attempt to install an assembly without a strong name"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by installing the **.NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK** component shipped with **VS 2019 Community**.